# How to program a pushbutton in matlab such that I can click it and it will start the process of the other function?

Tags: matlab, button, matlab-guide

So I have been having problems with my GUI where whenever I select an item from the list box, it automatically just outputs the file. Whereas I want it to just wait for the push button click. I am using GUIDE in matlab.

```css
index_selected = get(hObject,'Value');
Materials = {ABS,AL,CB,HIPS,KAOWOOL,Kydex,PEI,PET,PMMA,POM};
RMAT = (Materials(index_selected));
dlmwrite('Results.cmp',RMAT,'');
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the callback function of the listbox?

Comment: Please excuse me... Updated.

Answer (score 2):

The `listbox` callback is always executed when changing the element in the `listbox`. Move your code from the callback to the callback of the `button`.

```
index_selected = get(handles.handleToListbox,'Value');
Materials = {ABS,AL,CB,HIPS,KAOWOOL,Kydex,PEI,PET,PMMA,POM};
RMAT = (Materials(index_selected));
dlmwrite('Results.cmp',RMAT,'');
```

Then, only when pressing the `button`, the file will be created. Replace `handles.handleToListbox` with the actual correct handle name (see **tag** in the **object inspector**).